# Best Radioactive Isotopes for Energy Generation

Tags: energy, isotope, radioactivity, chemistry-in-fiction

First off, this is research for a video game storyline, I like to be thorough.

--

I am looking for the most efficient method of nuclear power generation which:

1. Can survive for hundreds/thousands of years (a no-brainer for isotopes)
2. Has some kind of non (or minimally) radioactive decay product/by-product.

The storyline is based in the 2050's, so I can use a little poetic license, I just want to get things as close to reality as possible.

This would be used to power a large city and scientific research base, for which several generators could be used, but I was wondering on which material would be best to generate such power consistently.

These facilities have consistent access to clean, flowing water so heavy water theoretically could be used in the energy generating process.

I started looking at our currently used isotopes, $\ce{^{234}U}$ and others, but I am looking for a material that would be compatible with both fusion and (what would then be legacy) fission (if possible).

$\ce{^{232}Th}$ seems like a promising start, but I thought I should ask before basing everything on extremely flawed science.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I always hoped that humanity would move beyond the realm of nuclear energy generation by 2050. Welcome to Chemistry.se though.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Doubt it, fusion reactors can start to be useful though.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on Worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on World Building.